# How to render a Widget inside a TreeView cell with GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm developing an application with Mono and Gtk#. Inside my app, I need to use the TreeView control. I'm looking for a way to render a widget inside a cell instead of drawing everything. I have custom widgets that I would like to use inside those cells and I don't want to draw them manually.

I have looked over documentations and forums but haven't found a way to do this. I don't think this is impossible since CellRendererCombo and CellRendererToggle seems to render a Widget.

Thanks

Comment: If you browse the source code for Gtk+, you will notice that the `CellRendererToggle` calls `gtk_paint_option` or `gtk_paint_check`, which are primitives that draw a radio button or a check box, not the actual widget (and I suspect the toggle/radio widget call the same primitive). On the other hand, `CellRendererCombo` displays a `ComboBox` or `ComboxBoxEntry` widget, but this happens in the `StartEditing` method override, which returns a `CellEditable` interface, which is one of the many interfaces that ComboBox and ComboBoxEntry implement.

Comment: If someone cares after five years of silence - this is possible. I have described some details while answering my own question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258691/gtk3-custom-cell-renderer-that-outputs-widgets/62477018#62477018
In short: you need a custom cell renderer, that operates on pointers to the item widgets (which lifecycle you have to support manually), and manually manage the connection between parent tv and item widgets, to make drawing, signaling and other item widget stuff working. Sorry for no sample code - I have it originally in Rust, which is hard to read.